# Uploading photos to Picasa Web Albums hangs

Tags: mac, photos, picasa

Uploading photos to my Picasa Web Album is hanging.  It starts out just fine, good speed, but then after about 5-10 photos, it doesn't upload as quickly, and it eventually just hangs.  I end up killing the Picasa3 process and starting the program up again to restart the upload.

**What is causing Picasa to be slow and hang when uploading photos?  Is there a setting that should be set?**

I constantly get the (retrying) message next to my upload progress percentage/bar.

- I'm using Picasa3 program on my Macbook Pro.
- I'm uploading some large albums (50-150 photo albums)
- The photos are high-quality
- Checking/Unchecking "Conserve bandwidth" doesn't help
- I do have broadband which performs well, it's just Picasa that's slow

Answer (score 1):

Are there any videos in the album you are uploading?

Those upload significantly slower than photos.

Comment: No there aren't.  But great point.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you manually updated to the latest version of Picasa?  I find the built in updater doesn't always find the latest version.  If not, do you have the same issue with the latest verion? (which may be 3.6.7)

Comment: I have the latest version (3.6.7), which I'm having these issues with.

Comment: Try reinstalling the latest version (via manual download) and also try rolling back to a previous version and seeing if you still have the same issue (you may want to try on a test duplicate set of photos just in case the latest version changes any library data)